# Looping through images using SpriteWidget

Tags: flutter, widget, sprite

I'm using SpriteWidget in Flutter.
https://github.com/spritewidget/spritewidget

I'm loading images like this:

```
// Load multiple images
await images.load([
  'assets/image_0.png',
  'assets/image_1.png',
  'assets/image_2.png',
]);

// Access a loaded image from the ImageMap
var image0 = images['assets/image_0.png'];
```

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through these images so that they are like an animated gif.  Show image_0 for half a second, then image_1 for half a second then image_2 for half a second and so on.

I understand that the usual and recommended way to do this is with a spritesheet, but I do not have a sprite sheet, only individual images.

Comment: Related question for anyone who finds this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770912/flutter-spritewidget-how-to-use-sprite-sheet

Answer (score 1):

How about using Sequences? You can loop over an array of images based on time.

https://github.com/spritewidget/spritewidget#sequences

Comment: Rather than sequences I ended up using just the simple update method.  https://github.com/spritewidget/spritewidget#handle-update-events